# How do I specify library and its include in meson cross file

Tags: c, cross-compiling, meson-build

I am trying to cross compile and build gst-rtsp-server for arm

I have run meson build but it always returned

```
Found CMake: NO
Run-time dependency glib-2.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
Looking for a fallback subproject for the dependency glib-2.0

meson.build:136:0: ERROR: Neither a subproject directory nor a glib.wrap file was found
```

.But i have already filled in the location in the meson crossfile

```
[properties]
c_args = ['-I/opt/linaro/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/7.5.0',
          '/home/monki/gstream/include/glib-2.0']
cpp_args = ['-I/opt/linaro/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/7.5.0',
        '/home/monki/gstream/include/glib-2.0']
objc_args = []
objcpp_args = []
c_link_args = ['-L/opt/linaro/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib64',
               '-L/home/monki/gstream/lib']
cpp_link_args = ['-L/opt/linaro/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib64',
         '-L/home/monki/gstream/lib']
```

What have I done wrongly?

Regards
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Meson is going to use pkg-config and cmake to look for glib, it doesn't care that you have -L and -I options, instead add

```
[built-in options]
pkg_config_path = ['/home/monki/gstream/lib/pkg-config', ...]
```

to your cross file. This instructs Meson to search those paths for host system dependencies when using pkg-config

(Depending on the version of meson you have you may need to use the `[properties]` section instead of the `[built-in options]` section.)

Comment: thanks for posting... I followed the examples at https://www.collabora.com/news-and-blog/blog/2020/05/15/cross-compiling-with-gst-build-and-gstreamer/   It seems to fill in the c_link_args and cpp_link_args with the library location